# How to switch Font Awesome Icons based on plain javascript and simple html

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I have been trying to switch font awesome icons without using jquery or another library, I want to switch the icon based on the theme and have some like this.

```
<a class="sidebar-link" onclick="themify()">
    <i id="theme-icon" class="fad fa-sun" style="--fa-secondary-opacity: 1;" aria hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="sidebar-link-text themer" id="theme-text">theme</span>
</a>
```

And as function

```
var state = "Day";
var prefers = "Day";

window.onload = function() {
if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme)').media !== 'not all') {
    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        prefers = "Night";
        document.getElementById("theme-icon").className = "fad fa-moon-stars";
    }
    state = prefers;
    document.getElementById('theme-text').innerHTML = state;
}


function themify() {
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
switch (state) {
    case "Day":
        state = "Night";
        document.getElementById('theme-text').innerHTML = state;
        document.getElementById('theme-icon').className = "fad fa-moon-stars";
        body.style.color = "white";
        body.style.backgroundColor = "#1c1c1c";
        break;

    case "Night":
        state = "Day";
        document.getElementById('theme-text').innerHTML = state;
        document.getElementById('theme-icon').className = "fad fa-sun";
        body.style.color = "black";
        body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        break;
    }
}
```

The state is defined with only two states; "Day" and "Night", this variable and the color switching of the body object works but after the page is loaded I am no longer able to change the icon. Do I need to directly modify the SVG ?

Found the solution (thanks John), If you are having the same problem use element.classlist.remove(); for every class item then add the new classes by element.classlist.add();

Comment: Use element.classList.add() and element.classList.remove()

Comment: Also you can use innerText rather than innerHTML for more security and speed if you don't require formatting

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095495/john your solution worked for me.